# Numbers standard cell dark mode

Tags: numbers, color, formatting, dark-mode

In Numbers, is there any way to make all standard cells of all spreadsheets (including existing spreadsheets created by others) be displayed in dark mode (i.e. have a black background with white text)?

I could imagine this working for all spreadsheets without having to manually set it up for each individual spreadsheet if:

- cells are allowed to not have a style, in which case all cells without a style without manual color changes would be displayed in dark mode
- a specific style that is used by convention as the standard style, in which case all cells of that style without manual color changes would be displayed in dark mode